# Setting NSPredicate for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a list of pin dropped on a map. Each pin has a list of photos attached.

Here is the Pin class

```
class Pin: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

@NSManaged var id: NSNumber
@NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber
@NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber
@NSManaged var album: [Photo]
@NSManaged var totalPagesCount: NSNumber?

lazy var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude as Double, longitude: self.longitude as Double)
}()

init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Pin", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    super.init(entity: entity,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    self.id = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}
}
```

and this is the Photo class:

```
class Photo: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var path: String?
@NSManaged var url: String
@NSManaged var pin: Pin

init(photoResponse: PhotoResponse, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    self.id = photoResponse.id
    self.url = photoResponse.url
}

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

func deletePhotoFile() {
    if let path = path {
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do {
            try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(path)
        } catch {}
    }
}
}
```

When I click on a pin, a new View Controller appears, downloading and showing the photos.

For this purpose, the View Controller has a lazy `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
lazy var fetchedPhotosController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Photo")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pin.id = %s", self.pin.id)
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: DataManager.getInstance().coreDataStackManager.managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Everything looks fine if I remove the predicate line, except that I receive all the photos in the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, and not only the ones belonging to the pin clicked.

If I set the predicate instead, I cannot get any update in the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

Why? I think something is wrong when setting the constraint for the ID of the pin associated with each photo, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your predicate to:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pin = %@", self.pin)
```

As you can directly compare to objects instead of trying to drill into this objects. Also, while %s is a valid format specifier it isn't the correct one to use with an `NSString` variable.